# Pulling quarks from one another creates a new pair of quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks

It is said that the force between two quarks increases as they are pulled apart which is ultimately resisted by the strong nuclear force.

Correct me if I'm wrong,  but my physics teacher once said that if I put enough energy to seperate two quarks, I end up creating a new pair of quarks. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the standard picture of quark creation looks like this: as two quarks are pulled apart, work is stored in the field that connects them. when the quantity of work stored this way is sufficient to pull another pair of quarks out of the vacuum, that's what happens, and you end up not with a pair of disconnected quarks, but two pairs. This is a simplified picture to which I invite the experts here to add details as they deem necessary.